# How to debug vue js app in chrome browser

Tags: vue.js, meteor

I have used vue js as a templating for meteor app. and when I try to debug it on chrome browser, I can't point out debugger pointer,It's not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VueJS devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en) can be useful to debug a lot of things.

Besides, a usual `debugger` should work, you only need to reach it during your code execution.